# A question about the definition of an outer measure that is defined by a measure on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra on $X$ and $\mu$ a measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$.

I know we can define an outer measure on $X$ by $$\forall{B\subseteq X}:\,\mu^{*}(B):=Inf\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{i})|\,\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}\supseteq B,A_{i}\in\mathcal{A}\}$$

Is there also a requirement that $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}\in\mathcal{A}$
 or does the definition above is the correct one ?

Comment: No, the countable union is not required to be in the algebra. The point of defining the outer measure is to extend $\mathcal{A}$ to a $\sigma$-algrebra -- the infinite union is in this $\sigma$-algebra. For an algebra, only finite unions are included by definition. See Bartle, chap. 9.

Comment: Note that
$$
  \inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k)|B\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k,A_k\in \mathcal A,\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\in \mathcal A\right\}

 = \inf\{\mu(A)|B\subseteq A,A\in \mathcal A\}
$$
which would be 1) easier to write and 2) not exactly what is needed to work with outer measures.